# Elasticsearch query for - either of the combination of two terms along with a must term

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to build a chat system which has groups/channels by default, and I am trying to fetch the chat history of a conversation in a channel from Elasticsearch given id of channel and users involved.

**Chat Model**

```
{
    "channel_id" : "ch_id_1",
    "sender_id" : "id_1",
    "sender_name" : "name_1",
    "recipient_id" : "id_2",
    "recipient_name" : "name_2",
    "created_at" : "2021-09-19T12:23:46.417748Z",
    "text" : "hi"
}
```

**ES Query**

```
{
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "must": [
                {
                    "term": {"channel_id": "ch_id_1"}
                }
            ],
            "should": [
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {"recipient_id": "id_1"}
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {"sender_id": "id_2"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                },
                {
                    "bool": {
                        "must": [
                            {
                                "term": {"recipient_id": "id_2"}
                            },
                            {
                                "term": {"sender_id": "id_1"}
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ],
            "minimum_should_match": 1
        }
    },
    "sort": [{"created_at": {"order": "desc"}}]
}
```

This is not retrieving any document. But if I remove `"minimum_should_match": 1`, it returns all the messages of channel.

I also tried moving channel id to both should queries which is also not retrieving anything.

```
{
    "bool": {
        "must": [
            {
                "term": {"channel_id": "ch_id_1"}
            },
            {
                "term": {"recipient_id": "id_1"}
            },
            {
                "term": {"sender_id": "id_2"}
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Query seems to be correct. I'm assuming that these are not nested fields and all of these fields are of type `keyword`. Could you please share your mapping details?

Comment: @OpsterESNinja-Kamal Okay, mappings were of type `text` and kind of messed up. Fixing that solved the problem. Thanks for pointing that out.